# EJB3 Mappings/ onetomany/manytoone how to handle relationships

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb-3.0

I am working with Java EE JSP/EJB3 and I have a problem implementing relations between tables. Initially I was thinking of storing the id but I've read that it would defeat the purpose of EJBs which store references to objects

As a test example to explain my problem I came up with a Car Model and a Car Brand relation. In this web application The user creates the brands first.  then create the cars and select the brand from a dropdown.

Car  ->rand: many to one
Brand->Car: one to many

```
public class Brand implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="id")
  private long id;

  @Column(name="brand_name")
  private String brand_name;

  @Column(name="cars_fk")
  private Set<Car> cars;
...

}
```

The following is the car Entitybean

```
public class Car implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="id")
  private long id;

  private Brand brand;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Column(name="brand_FK")
  private Brand brand;
...

}
```

Given that the above is correct (which I'm not sure of)

What is the best practice to handle inputting of these

lets say i have this html ( if the select has to be different please do tell )

```
<form action="processCar.jsp">
  Model: <input type="text" name="title"><br>

  <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select> 

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The brand options are loaded from the  Brand.findAll.

Also if this is correct, where does the change over from  brand name/id to an entity object Brand is done ? in the session bean ?

```
public void createCar(String title,String brandname){
   Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Brand.getBrandbyName");
   query.setParameter("brand_name", brandname);
   Brand brand = (Brand)query.getSingleResult();
   carSLSBManagement.create(title,brand);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your declaration of the `cars` field in `Brand` looks wrong. It's `@OneToMany`, which means it can't use a `@Column`, because there can be no single column for it in the entity's table. Rather, you should say `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "brand")`, and have it driven by the `brand` field in the `Car` entity's table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do this would be to use the ID as the value in the drop-down, and then to convert it to an object as soon as possible in the code that receives the request. That would be a servlet or equivalent, rather than a bean. The bean should work with objects that have already been fetched.

If you have the ID of the brand, then fetching it is as simple as:

```
long brandId = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("brandId"));
Brand brand = em.find(Brand.class, brandId);
```

I will add that although my preference is to do all the parameter parsing and decoding in the web layer, before going to the domain layer, it might be more convenient for technical reasons for you to push some of it downwards into the domain layer. For example, you should have a transaction open when you do the `em.find`, and if you are using a classic Java EE architecture with servlets and EJBs, then transactions naturally begin at the EJBs, with the servlets being non-transactional. To fit in with that, you could parse the ID to a long in the servlet, but fetch the object in the EJB. That's a little more clunky, but it does mean you don't have to mess about with transactions.

Comment: Why do you fetch it as soon as possible? I thought that ideally one should do entitybean operations at the ejb tier. to keep a saperation vetween the war tier and ejb tier. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I believe it's best to get from raw strings to real objects as soon as possible, to ensure type safety and consistent use of domain concepts. I don't think there's any particular reason to confine database operations to the EJB layer; i think that's a hangover from prescriptive, architecture-first habits of the bad old days of EJB 1 and 2. Remember that persistent objects aren't "entity beans" any more, they're just objects!

Comment: Using entities instead of DTOs means that you must access entity manager directly from the web application or through local ejb. This will increase the attack surface slightly. Use of DTOs will however increase the developement time and remoting does incur a performance penalty.